# Ternary operator not working with inline styles with React [Hooks]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Basically, I have a state that is a true or false. The state name is DisplayFirstColorPicker. If its true, I want the inline style to be the const 'showColorPicker', if its false, it should be the const 'hideColorPicker'.

However, when I run the inline Ternary operator, I get a "Failed to compile" error.

Any idea whats wrong?

The inline code:

State:

```
  const [displayFirstColorPicker, setDisplayFirstColorPicker] = useState(false)
```

Inline code

```
<div class="firstColorPicker" style={{DisplayFirstColorPicker ? {showColorPicker} : {hideColorPicker}}}>
```

The consts

```
const showColorPicker = {
    display: "block",
  }

  const hideColorPicker = {
    display: "none",
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing all kinds of weird stuff here. You have one too many braces on the outside, and also should not be using object short hand notation like `{showColorPicker}` which would compile to `{ showColorPicker: { display: none} }`

`style={DisplayFirstColorPicker ? showColorPicker : hideColorPicker}` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I am still getting used to JSX. Keep forgetting that once I am in the curly braces, I am free to write JS and I dont have to wrap every const in curly braces.

Comment: Yeah it's straight up javascript in there :) so unlses there's mores styles, some people might do `styles={{ display: DisplayFirstColorPicker ? 'block': 'none'}}`